# Armazenar data de JTextField em tabela MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, data, netbeans, conversão

Eu preciso digitar uma data num `JTextField` do netbeans juntamente com outros dados e armazenar tudo isso numa tabela [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

O problema é que tenho que digitar o formato `dd/MM/yyyy` no `JTextField` e armazenar no formato `yyyy-MM-dd` no MySQL.

Segue o código do método:

```java
private void emitirvenda(){
        String sql = "insert into tbcontas (data_venda, produto, valor, idcli) values (?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, txt_ProdVenda.getText()); //campo onde quero informar data
            pst.setString(2, txt_ProdVenda.getText());
            pst.setString(3, txt_ValorVenda.getText().replace(",","."));
            pst.setString(4, txt_IdCliVenda.getText());
            if ((txt_ProdVenda.getText().isEmpty()) || (txt_ValorVenda.getText().isEmpty()) || (txt_IdCliVenda.getText().isEmpty())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Preencha todos os campos obrigatórios");
            } else {
                int add = pst.executeUpdate();
                if (add>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Produto adicionado à conta");
                    txt_ProdVenda.setText(null);
                    txt_ValorVenda.setText(null);
                    atualizarTabela();
                    atualizarTotal();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```